# A question about differential forms

Tags: real-analysis, differential-forms

I have checked Rudin's proof about Poincaré Lemma (Principles of Mathematical Analysis) and it seems to have a mistake. Through Google, I found another guy who has noted such error. More details [here](http://mathforum.org/kb/thread.jspa?forumID=13&threadID=2141549&messageID=7208112).
And I look through the other books about differential forms, but they just talked about $C^\infty$.

$\mbox{}$
    [image]

Comment: the sum of continuous forms is continuous as the coefficients add in the natural manner. If I read his proof correctly, by that point his induction hypothesis indicates the continuity of each piece which builds $\gamma$ hence $\gamma$ is continuous.

Comment: I don't think he says $\gamma$ is smooth, he says there in $Y_{p-1}$ which as I read it says they're once continuously differentiable. ($p-1$ refers to form degree)

Comment: But why DjFi is continuously differentiable?

Comment: If $F_i$ was $C^2$ then $D_jF_i$ would be $C^1$. However, I see you say he only assumes $C^1$ which also leaves me puzzled.

Answer (score 1):

The ambiguity goes away when coefficients are taken in the basis of $\Omega^k(M)$ given by wedges $dx_{i_1}\wedge\cdots\wedge dx_{i_k}$  of **ordered** tuples of $1$-forms $(dx_{i_1},\ldots,dx_{i_k})$ where $i_1<\cdots<i_k$.

Comment: Could you please elaborate? And I want know why d(dw)=0,when w belongs to class C^1