# Rudin's proof on Poincare Lemma.

Tags: real-analysis, differential-forms

Two identical questions are here:

[A question about differential forms](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/565205/a-question-about-differential-forms)

and here:

http://mathforum.org/kb/thread.jspa?forumID=13&threadID=2141549&messageID=7208112

In his proof, Rudin says that $\gamma$ is "clearly" $C^1$, which I found a bit confusing. Each $F_i$ was $C^1$ as proved, why is it clear that $\gamma$ is also $C^1$? Doesn't it require each $F_i$ to be $C^2$ in order for the partial derivatives to be $C^1$?

The problem is on the bottom of page 279 of Principles of Mathematical Analysis.

*Rudin's Original Text Shot:*
[image]

Comment: After looking at this for a couple of hours I don't see any way around the conclusion that there is a gap in the proof.  Not only is it not clear why the $D_j F_I$ are $C^1$ but it is also unclear why $d^2\beta=0$, the theorem to that effect in Rudin assuming $\beta$ is in $C^2$.  At  this point one has to ask:  is it in fact true that closed $\omega$'s in $C^1$ are exact?

Comment: Thank you! I've done some research on the Poincare Lemma from other sources, and their statements of the lemma indeed involve infinite differentiability.