# Question about Rudin's proof of poincare lemma

Tags: real-analysis, differential-forms

Here's Rudin's full proof of poincare lemma
[Rudin's proof on Poincare Lemma.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1588789/rudins-proof-on-poincare-lemma)

I just have one question, why do we need $E$ to be convex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To guarantee that $f$ does not depend on $x_j$ for $j>p$. Being convex, you can put a path along the axis of each variable where the derivative is zero, so $f$ is constant in that variable (that the derivative is zero at a single point would not be enough for this) .

Comment: but the proof said the derivative is zero for all $x \in E$, it's still not enough?

Comment: No, of course not. Consider $f(x,y)=x^2+y^2$ and let $E=\{(s,t):\ s,t>0\}\cup\{(0,0)\}$. Then the fact that $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(0,0)=0$ does not tell you that $f$ does not depend on $y$.

Comment: I understand derivative is zero at a single point would not be enough. I am confused that in the proof $(116)$, $D_{j}f(x)=0$ where $p<j\leq n$ and $x \in E$. Take this example, it's true that $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(0,0)=0$, but $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(s,t) \neq 0$ at other point. Does this contradict $(116)$? I thought $(116)$ told us the partial derivative is zero at all points